# TargetInvocationException When Storing and Retrieving Image Using Async Await

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, asynchronous, async-await

I have been stuck on this for a while now, I'm clearly missing something. I am using async await methods to store and retrieve an image from PhotoChooserTask in my application. If a user wishes to use PhotoChooserTask to select an image, I save that image and then display it to the user. The first time around this works great. The second time I get a System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException error. From what I can tell it seems that this is occurs after PhotoChooserTask is called again and I go through the saving/retrieving process to display the image to the user and keep in storage. My code is below, along with a screenshot of the error. I cannot narrow down where exactly the issue is occurring..

`SettingsPage.xaml.cs`

```
protected override async void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
  base.OnNavigatedTo(e);

  try
  {
    BitmapImage bmp = await tsh.RetrievePhoto(Settings.BackgroundImageName.Value);
    TransparentModeViewBoxImage.Source = bmp;
  }
  catch(Exception ex)
  {
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "OnNavigatedTo Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK);
  }
}

async void photoChooserTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
  if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
  {
    Remove_Click(null, null);

    try
    {
      //Clear the TransparentModeViewBoxImage.Source before applying new image
      TransparentModeViewBoxImage.Source = null;

      // get the file stream and file name
      Stream photoStream = e.ChosenPhoto;
      string extension = Path.GetExtension(e.OriginalFileName);
      string fileName = Constants.BackgroundImageName + extension;
      Settings.BackgroundImageName.Value = fileName;

      //Save the photo for later use
      await tsh.StorePhoto(photoStream, Settings.BackgroundImageName.Value);

      //Code to display the photo on the page in an image control named TransparentModeViewBoxImage.
      BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
      bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
      TransparentModeViewBoxImage.Source = bmp;
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
      MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "PhotoChooserTask Exception", MessageBoxButton.OK);
    }
  }
}

private void Remove_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TransparentModeViewBoxImage.Source = null;
    }
```

`TombstoningHelper.cs` (where the storing/retrieving is done)

```
public async Task StorePhoto(Stream photoStream, string fileName)
{
  // persist data into isolated storage
  StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);

  using (Stream current = await file.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
  {
    await photoStream.CopyToAsync(current);
  }
}

public async Task<BitmapImage> RetrievePhoto(string fileName)
{
  StorageFile file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync(fileName);
  Stream imageStream = await file.OpenStreamForReadAsync();

  // display the file as image
  BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
  bi.SetSource(imageStream);

  return bi;
}
```

And the error

[image]

EDIT** After adding try catch blocks in `OnNavigatedTo` and `PhotoChooserTask` methods

I have two pages, a MainPage and SettingsPage. SettingsPage is where i use PhotoChooserTask and display the result to the user so he or she may decide whether to choose another image or not. I actually use the image within MainPage. The error occurs once the user navigates back from SettingsPage after choosing an image to show in MainPage, and then going back into SettingsPage to choose another image. If a user starts the application from the app list or start screen, and then goes directly to SettingsPage, the issue does not occur. Essentially once a user selects an image from SettingsPage and then returns to SettingsPage to choose a new image, the error occurs, but if a user starts from a fresh state starting the app and then goes SettingsPage to choose an image, everything works fine. The error I get when going back to SettingsPage and choosing an image after already doing this once in the same app instance is `Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`.

Comment: You have to put the `try catch` around your code and check for the inner exception. The message shows in inner exception is the actual problem.

Comment: @nvoigt Your request has been accepted :)

Comment: @loop You mean place a try catch in the `StorePhoto` method?

Comment: at the outermost level.because your app is crashing so exception will reach to all above level to this code. actually i got the same problem before. e.g apply in both. photoChooserTask_Completed,OnNavigatedTo and catch the exception and see message.

Comment: Ok this is interesting. When first gathering the image from PhotoChooser Task I caught an Exception in OnNavigatedTo stating `Offset and length were out of bounds for the array or count is greater than the number of elements from index to the end of the source collection.` but the image loaded fine. When I go to get a new photo using PhotoChooserTask I then catch an exception in the PhotoChooserTask method stating `Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT:0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`.

Comment: it is better you updated your question with this info. so that other people ans it too.

Comment: Is there anything in the output pane in VS?  It *sounds* like there may be a binding issue and it may be giving you some information in the output pane before throwing an exception

Comment: When the issue occurs I do see `A first chance exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll` in the output window. It's weird because after adding the try catch blocks to retrieve the error message I notice sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. I cannot narrow down the situations when it doesn't work it seems random? I added a click event above I use to remove the image from displaying if the user so chooses, and I have added a call to this `Remove_Click` event in the `PhotoChooserTask_Completed` event which seems to help sometimes.